# R & Postgis: ERROR: Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny, postgis, r-sf

The code below enables me to add polygons I draw on a leaflet map to tables in my database.
However I have some difficulties since the geometry column of my table is called "geom" and the geometry column created with the leaflet map is called "geometry".

I get a warning message like this:

> `"Error in : Failed to initialise COPY: ERREUR:  the column "geometry" does not exists"`

```
ui <- fluidPage(leafletOutput("map"))
 
server <-  function(input, output, session){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
  leaflet() %>%  
  addTiles(group = "OSM") %>%
  addDrawToolbar(targetLayerId = NULL, targetGroup = NULL,
                 polygonOptions = drawPolygonOptions(showArea = TRUE, metric=TRUE, shapeOptions=drawShapeOptions(fillColor="aquamarine", fillOpacity=0.8, clickable = TRUE), repeatMode=FALSE),
                 polylineOptions = FALSE, 
                 circleOptions = FALSE, 
                 rectangleOptions = FALSE, 
                 markerOptions = FALSE,
                 circleMarkerOptions = FALSE,
                 singleFeature = FALSE,
                 editOptions = FALSE)})

  observeEvent(input$map_draw_new_feature, {
polygon_coordinates <- input$map_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates[[1]]
drawn_polygon <- Polygon(do.call(rbind,lapply(polygon_coordinates,function(x){c(x[[1]][1],x[[2]][1])})))

sps <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(drawn_polygon),"drawn_polygon")))
created_polygon  <- st_as_sf(sps, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

st_write(created_polygon , pool, "mytable", append = TRUE)
})


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I solve this without altering the column in my database ?

---

**EDIT:**

I tried something ugly like this:

```
created_polygon$geom <- created_polygon$geometry  
    
created_polygon<- created_polygon%>% st_drop_geometry()
```

But I get this warning message

> `"Warning: Error in : COPY returned error: ERROR:  Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing that `created_polygon` is an `sf` object, you can rename the `geometry` column using `st_geometry(nc) <- "geom"`.

Please, find below a reprex.

NB: you need to have the version of `sf` 1.0.6 or higher (if not, please uncomment the first rows of the reprex)

**Reprex**

- Importing data and reading `nc` object (i.e. the `geometry` column is named `"geometry"`)

```r
#> library(devtools)
#> install_github("r-spatial/sf")

library(sf)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

nc
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> First 10 features:
#>     AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID        NAME  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74
#> 1  0.114     1.442  1825    1825        Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1
#> 2  0.061     1.231  1827    1827   Alleghany 37005  37005        3   487     0
#> 3  0.143     1.630  1828    1828       Surry 37171  37171       86  3188     5
#> 4  0.070     2.968  1831    1831   Currituck 37053  37053       27   508     1
#> 5  0.153     2.206  1832    1832 Northampton 37131  37131       66  1421     9
#> 6  0.097     1.670  1833    1833    Hertford 37091  37091       46  1452     7
#> 7  0.062     1.547  1834    1834      Camden 37029  37029       15   286     0
#> 8  0.091     1.284  1835    1835       Gates 37073  37073       37   420     0
#> 9  0.118     1.421  1836    1836      Warren 37185  37185       93   968     4
#> 10 0.124     1.428  1837    1837      Stokes 37169  37169       85  1612     1
#>    NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79                       geometry
#> 1       10  1364     0      19 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...
#> 2       10   542     3      12 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3...
#> 3      208  3616     6     260 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3...
#> 4      123   830     2     145 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3...
#> 5     1066  1606     3    1197 MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.21767 3...
#> 6      954  1838     5    1237 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.74506 3...
#> 7      115   350     2     139 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3...
#> 8      254   594     2     371 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.56251 3...
#> 9      748  1190     2     844 MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.30876 3...
#> 10     160  2038     5     176 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.02567 3...
```

- Code to rename the `geometry` column

```r
st_geometry(nc) <- "geom"
```

- Output (i.e. `"geometry"` has been changed into `"geom"`)

```
nc
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> First 10 features:
#>     AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID        NAME  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74
#> 1  0.114     1.442  1825    1825        Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1
#> 2  0.061     1.231  1827    1827   Alleghany 37005  37005        3   487     0
#> 3  0.143     1.630  1828    1828       Surry 37171  37171       86  3188     5
#> 4  0.070     2.968  1831    1831   Currituck 37053  37053       27   508     1
#> 5  0.153     2.206  1832    1832 Northampton 37131  37131       66  1421     9
#> 6  0.097     1.670  1833    1833    Hertford 37091  37091       46  1452     7
#> 7  0.062     1.547  1834    1834      Camden 37029  37029       15   286     0
#> 8  0.091     1.284  1835    1835       Gates 37073  37073       37   420     0
#> 9  0.118     1.421  1836    1836      Warren 37185  37185       93   968     4
#> 10 0.124     1.428  1837    1837      Stokes 37169  37169       85  1612     1
#>    NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79                           geom
#> 1       10  1364     0      19 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...
#> 2       10   542     3      12 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3...
#> 3      208  3616     6     260 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3...
#> 4      123   830     2     145 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3...
#> 5     1066  1606     3    1197 MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.21767 3...
#> 6      954  1838     5    1237 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.74506 3...
#> 7      115   350     2     139 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3...
#> 8      254   594     2     371 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.56251 3...
#> 9      748  1190     2     844 MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.30876 3...
#> 10     160  2038     5     176 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.02567 3...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**EDIT**

As a follow-up to your comment, please find below the way to change the geometry type from `MULTIPOLYGON` to `POLYGON`

```r
library(sf)

# Geometry type at the origin : MULTIPOLYGON
unique(st_geometry_type(nc))
#> [1] MULTIPOLYGON
#> 18 Levels: GEOMETRY POINT LINESTRING POLYGON MULTIPOINT ... TRIANGLE
```

- Code to convert geometry type from `MULTIPOLYGON` to `POLYGON`

```r
nc <- st_cast(nc, "POLYGON")
#> Warning in st_cast.sf(nc, "POLYGON"): repeating attributes for all sub-
#> geometries for which they may not be constant
```

- Output: the geometry is now of type `POLYGON`

```r
unique(st_geometry_type(nc))
#> [1] POLYGON
#> 18 Levels: GEOMETRY POINT LINESTRING POLYGON MULTIPOINT ... TRIANGLE
```

- Last check (please see the `geom` column)

```r
nc
#> Simple feature collection with 108 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> First 10 features:
#>      AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID        NAME  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74
#> 1   0.114     1.442  1825    1825        Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1
#> 2   0.061     1.231  1827    1827   Alleghany 37005  37005        3   487     0
#> 3   0.143     1.630  1828    1828       Surry 37171  37171       86  3188     5
#> 4   0.070     2.968  1831    1831   Currituck 37053  37053       27   508     1
#> 4.1 0.070     2.968  1831    1831   Currituck 37053  37053       27   508     1
#> 4.2 0.070     2.968  1831    1831   Currituck 37053  37053       27   508     1
#> 5   0.153     2.206  1832    1832 Northampton 37131  37131       66  1421     9
#> 6   0.097     1.670  1833    1833    Hertford 37091  37091       46  1452     7
#> 7   0.062     1.547  1834    1834      Camden 37029  37029       15   286     0
#> 8   0.091     1.284  1835    1835       Gates 37073  37073       37   420     0
#>     NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79                           geom
#> 1        10  1364     0      19 POLYGON ((-81.47276 36.2343...
#> 2        10   542     3      12 POLYGON ((-81.23989 36.3653...
#> 3       208  3616     6     260 POLYGON ((-80.45634 36.2425...
#> 4       123   830     2     145 POLYGON ((-76.00897 36.3196...
#> 4.1     123   830     2     145 POLYGON ((-76.02717 36.5567...
#> 4.2     123   830     2     145 POLYGON ((-75.90199 36.5562...
#> 5      1066  1606     3    1197 POLYGON ((-77.21767 36.2409...
#> 6       954  1838     5    1237 POLYGON ((-76.74506 36.2339...
#> 7       115   350     2     139 POLYGON ((-76.00897 36.3196...
#> 8       254   594     2     371 POLYGON ((-76.56251 36.3405...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Your answer look simple and promising but it seems I can't download a more recent version of the package 'sf' 1.0-5 ;(

Comment: @zakros, thanks for your feedback. Could you explain a little more about the kind of problems you encounter when you try to install the development version of `sf`? Do you work with windows or MacOS?

Comment: I get many warning lines ending with this error message: `In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/USER~1/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpe8ru7f/file2a8074054ffd/sf_1.0-6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status`. I'm working with Windows but this issue with sf may remain a problem since the shiny app I'm developping will have to be deployed on my shiny server...

Comment: @zakros, thanks for the clarification. If you are working on Windows, the first two lines of code in the `reprex` indicated as comments should normally work... I also sometimes get the same error message as yours when I try to update some libraries. In this case, (i) I close all open files in R, (ii) I close R, (iii) I open R again, and (4), in this case, I run: `library(devtools)` ; `install_github("r-spatial/sf")` ... and it should work... I keep my fingers crossed for you :-)

Comment: closing all files in R and restarting it enabled me to download the 1.0-6 version of 'sf' but unfortunately your answer didn't erase the error message `Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)`

Comment: Yes, I see. You just need to change the geometry type using the `st_cast()` function from the `sf` library. It's up to you, either try it yourself or add an excerpt of your data (e.g. using `dput(head(created_polygon))`) so I can help you with that.

Comment: @zakros. O.K., in fact, no need of your data. I added an edit at the bottom of my answer to show you how to do that. Hope this helps. Cheers.